# Expanding a variable inside quotes

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

am trying to get the files from S3 bucket,starting with certain prefix. To do so am using aws cli command in the bash script.

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash  

FILESIZE=$(mktemp)
declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0" )
for n in "${!files[@]}"; do
    printf '%8d  %s\n' "${n}" ${files[n]}
 echo aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)')]"
```

done

In my code there is a problem when expanding variables inside the quotes, **$(date +%m%d)**Date variable is expanding but i need to avoid single quotes   **'A1S00526'**. How can i do that
Pls help me

Output:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D1S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D2S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D3S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D4S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D5S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D6S00526')]
```

Expected output:

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, A1S00526)]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, D1S00526)]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, D2S00526)]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, D3S00526)]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, D4S00526)]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, D5S00526)]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, D6S00526)]
```

Can someone pls help me to expand the variables inside the quotes

When i run code as below, please find the attached output

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query \'"Contents[?contains(Key, ${files[n]}$(date +%m%d))]"\'
```

[image]

Comment: How should the output that you want to have look like?

Comment: You don't want the quotes? then remove it?

Comment: @Jetchisel  `'${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)'` the quote is the syntax  of aws s3api command,,,If i remove error will occur...My output should be like `A1S00526`

Comment: @KamilCuk My output should be like `A1S00526`

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588958/expanding-a-variable-inside-quotes), which already has an answer (but requires more clarification). Please don't post duplicate questions; pick the most appropriate forum, and ask there.

Comment: @GordonDavisson What clarification u r expecting..can  u pls let me know

Comment: @Kanagambala : I can not understand from your question what output you want to see from the `echo` command, as opposed to the output you get.

Comment: @user1934428  my expected output is `aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, A1S00526)]`

Comment: But this is exactly what you claim that you would get, except that you produce single quotes in additon. But if you don't want them why do you write them?

Comment: @user1934428  single quote is the syntax of aws s3spi commnad...If i remove syntax error will occurr

Comment: Then leave them in. But when you wrote _ my expected output is_ , I don't see any quotes in what you expect. But after all, what is the problem then? Your `echo` produces exactly the string which you expect.

Comment: @user1934428 I have edited my question. I posted my expected output...Can u pls help me

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILESIZE=$(mktemp)
declare -a files=("A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0")
for n in "${!files[@]}"; do
    #printf '%8d  %s\n' "${n}" ${files[n]}
    echo aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query \'"Contents[?contains(Key, ${files[n]}$(date +%m%d))]"\'
done
```

The output will be:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, A1S00526)]'
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, D1S00526)]'
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, D2S00526)]'
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, D3S00526)]'
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, D4S00526)]'
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, D5S00526)]'
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, D6S00526)]'
```

Comment: single quote is the syntax of aws s3spi commnad...If i remove syntax error will occurr –

Comment: Have you referred to the official documentation for `aws s3api`? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html#examples

Comment: If i run like `aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, ${files[n]}$(date +%m%d))]"` am getting error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`

Comment: When i run the code as u suggested, am getting the output as attached in the question section...Could u pls help me

Comment: @Kanagambala: Do you run it y copy and pasting the command? Then the quotes are correct, and I don't see your problem.

Comment: @user1934428 Please refer the ouput of the snippet which i attached lately and i have attached the code

Comment: We can not see in your originally posted script, how the command gets executed. The script is incomplete (for instance, the `done` is missing). Still, I have updated my answer to include an example of how to run the command. If this is not sufficient, I think your question needs to be closed, because its scope is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you write you `echo` as

```
echo aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, ${files[n]}$(date +%m%d))]"
```

you will get exactly the output you expected. If you actually want to **run** the command, and it is important that the quotes are passed to `aws`, it becomes

```
for n in "${!files[@]}"; do
  printf '%8d  %s\n' "${n}" ${files[n]}
  aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)')]" 
done
```

In short: You want the quotes, you put them in. You don't want them, you leave them out.

Comment: If i ran  `aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, ${files[n]}$(date +%m%d))]"` am getting the error as `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`

Comment: You don't indicate in your posting, what (and how) you are running the command. You just asked for what output to expect from the _echo_ command. You need to ask **precisely**, what you want to get. And, put this information into the question, not in a comment.